# sql create table errors MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql

write a sql sentence to create a table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE fb_web_user_feeds(id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,host_id bigint,,author varchar(64),time varchar(64),user_feed text)
```

BUT IT ERRORS:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'author varchar(64),time varchar(64),user_feed text)' at line 1")
```

could you please tell me the reason

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have 2 commas here:

```
host_id bigint,,author varchar(64)
```

It should just be 1 comma making your syntax be:

```
 CREATE TABLE fb_web_user_feeds(id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,host_id bigint,author varchar(64),time varchar(64),user_feed text)
```